# json_decode in php process some special character

Tags: php, json

Here is the php code:

```
$str='{"key":"'.chr(1).'"}';
$json=json_decode($str);
```

json_decode return null. So how should I process the $str in order to decode. (P.S. $str here is just a example, it may include chr(2), chr(10) and so on).

Comment: That is strange while `json_decode('{"key":"\r\n"}')` workes fine `json_decode('{"key":"'.chr(10).chr(13).'"}')` returns `NULL`.

Comment: $json = json_decode($str,true).......try with this once

Comment: @Venkat nope that doesn't work

Comment: rekire: `json_decode('{"key":"\r\n"}')` does not put the characters 10 and 13 into the string - it puts literal slashes. this code does what you expect: `json_decode("{\"key\":\"\r\n\"}")` (and so fails as expected)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Only characters in the range U+0020-U+0021, U+0023-U+005B, U+005D-U+10FFFF may appear unescaped in strings.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627#section-2.5) Any other character must be escaped using the Unicode escape sequence. In your case use `\u0001` instead.

Comment: `chr(10).chr(13)` is actually `\n\r`, but your point still stands. oneproblem is that your code example does not do what you expect above (i will comment there too). the other is that you cannot have bare carriages returns in a json string

Comment: @rekire ‘Should’ as in ‘disregarding what the spec says, it should work as it works with other languages, too’?

Answer (score 1):

As Gumbo points out, you are not generating valid JSON. If you must do this (unsure why, your example is basic a no-op), then use `json_encode()`:

```
$str = '{"key":'.json_encode(chr(1).chr(2)).'}';
$json = json_decode($str);
```

This creates valid JSON:

```
{"key":"\u0001\u0002"}
```

And will decode correctly.

Comment: Actually, $str is not got from php code, it is got from a web server which is writen by other language. So do you have method to filter the invaild character in $str?

Comment: Oh, you're saying you're getting invalid JSON from another process? In that case, I strongly suggest fixing the other process. If you can't, you're going to need to find out exactly what it *does* escape, then write a filter to fix this things it misses.

Comment: At some language, string and list are the same type, `"abc"==[97,98,99]` and `"中文"==[228,184,173,230,150,135]`, So, I am finding a filter function to process the list.

Comment: Now I make another process return an integer array, and convert the array to string at php. Thanks